# How to solve a limit to negative infinity of a function with cos and sin?

Tags: limits, analysis

Does anyone know how to solve the following limit? I've tried using the squeeze theorem, or rewriting it, but I seem to get nowhere when doing that. Does anyone know how one would go about solving something like this?

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x\cos(x^{2})+3x\sqrt{1-4x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}+\sin(x^{5})}$$

Comment: Typically all you can know is that $\sin(~)$ is going to return a number somewhere between $-1$ and $1$.  You should hope that everything else is going to overshadow that, which is indeed what happens here.

Comment: More precisely: since $x$ is getting large (in absolute value), what is the largest power of $x$ that appears in the numerator? What is the largest power of $x$ that appears in the denominator? Those should be the dominant terms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the above comment, without trying to give a formal proof with $L$ and $\epsilon$, you can break this down and just focus on powers of $x$ in the top and bottom (not that different than a simpler problem of a ratio of polynomials as $x\rightarrow+\infty$).

Divide by $x$.

Now the numerator is:

$cos(x^2)+3\sqrt{1-4x}$

And the denominator is:

$\frac1x\space\sqrt[4]{x^6-x^5} + \frac{sin(x^5)}x$

The $cos$ term is bounded, and the term with $sin$ approaches $0$. So we can focus on the ratio of the others. [This is handled with more detail in the above subsequent answer.]

As $x\rightarrow-\infty$:

The remaining top term approaches $6\sqrt{-x}=6\sqrt{|x|}$.

And the remaining bottom term approaches $\frac1x |x|^{3/2}=\frac1x|x|\sqrt{|x|}=-\sqrt{|x|}$.

Therefore the original expression approaches $-6$ as $x\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: The third- and second-to-last-lines are vague enough to be misleading. One function doesn't "go to" another function.

Comment: @GregMartin this was supposed to be a bit heuristic in line with simpler problems where you look at highest powers; is "approaches as x goes to neg. infinity" better or are you saying this is not really valid reasoning? (appreciate the feedback BTW).

Comment: I think it's better to divide both top and bottom by $|x|^{3/2}$ rather than $x$. Then every individual term tends to a finite limit as $x\to-\infty$, and the arithmetic limit laws apply rigorously.

Comment: Fair enough, and in retrospect yes.  Started with $x$ since it was common in the numerator and helped do away with the trig functions.

Comment: Well, I would propose that "the sin and cos terms are bounded so can effectively be ignored" is also vague enough to be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to treat $\cos$ and $\sin$ as if they were just random number generators that return a value in the interval $[-1, 1]$.

So, for the numerator of your limand, $N(x) := x\cos(x^{2})+3x\sqrt{1-4x}$, you have:

$$x + 3x\sqrt{1-4x} \le N(x) \le -x+3x\sqrt{1-4x}$$

(Since you're taking the limit as $x$ goes to *negative* infinity, we can assume $x < 0$, hence having $x$ on the left and $-x$ on the right.)

And for the denominator, $D(x) := \sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}+\sin(x^{5})$, we have:

$$\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}} - 1 \le D(x) \le \sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}+1$$

The left-hand side of the inequality is zero if $x \approx -0.8812714616335696$.  But if $x$ is below that value, then $D(x)$ is positive.  Thus, as $x \to -\infty$, we have:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}} - 1} \ge \frac{1}{D(x)} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}+1}$$

Combining this with the previous inequality for $N(x)$, we get:

$$\frac{x + 3x\sqrt{1-4x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}+1} \le \frac{N(x)}{D(x)} \le \frac{-x + 3x\sqrt{1-4x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}-1}$$

You should be able to show that the bounding functions $L(x) := \frac{x + 3x\sqrt{1-4x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}+1}$ and $U(x) := \frac{-x + 3x\sqrt{1-4x}}{\sqrt[4]{x^{6}-x^{5}}-1}$ have the same limit, and then the Squeeze Theorem gives you the limit of the original expression.

Comment: This was what I originally had done, but I wasn't able to properly work it out. I eventually ended up that the limit goes to negative infinity, which I don't think is quite true, but I cannot determine where I went wrong. What steps do you take from here on out?

Comment: @RonanFinn: You can use L'Hospital's Rule.  Or note that both N(x) and D(x) are asymptotically $O(x^{3/2})$...

Comment: @Dan I like how you formalized what I hand-waved on the oscillating terms..